# Deprecation warning for format - but I am specifying format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using moment.js, I keep getting the format warning in the browser console:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or
>   ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not
>   reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date
>   formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major
>   release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments:

But as far as I can tell, I specified the format as per the docs:

```
const checkToday = (targetDate)=> {
  return chartData
    .filter(curve => moment(curve.date, "MM-DD-YYYY").isBefore(targetDate, 'day'));
};

if (chartData) {
  // addd # days to today
  const targetDate = moment().add(days, 'days').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
  return checkToday(targetDate);
}
```

Where is it complaining that I am not specifying the format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
.filter(curve => moment(curve.date, "MM-DD-YYYY").isBefore(targetDate, 'day'));
```

You are passing a string to `.isBefore` that is created in this line:

```
const targetDate = moment().add(days, 'days').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

The format you are using for that string "MM-DD-YYYY" is what moment is complaining about. Acceptable formats are found [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

Comment: Thanks for me works to change the format from ('MM-DD-YYYY') to ('YYYY-MM-DD')